# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »Auftrag« und »Aufgabe«?

Tags: meaning, difference

Laut [Leo](http://dict.leo.org) können beide Wörter zum Beispiel *task* und *mission* beudeuten.

Comment: So, and what about the other 30 translations, Leo suggests? ... ironie-off — I really dislike such questions that suggest that there was no effort put into solving the issue.

Comment: @Em1 not sure why you think this is "proof reading, spell checking, or translation of individual texts". It's a general question about when to use one word or another, for better understanding the denotation and connotation of certain German words.

Comment: @tofro the question content states I was stumped by dictionaries giving me overlapping translations but not explaning the difference.

Comment: I do not think that this question should be closed as the answers demonstrate that the distinction is nothing that can be easily deduced from a dictionary. Remember that closure is about avoiding answers (that are inherently problematic, e.g., because they can only repeat dictionary entries), not for punishing lazy questions (that’s what downvotes are for).

Comment: @neotryte: “What topics can I ask about here?” is the only help-centre site that we can edit. Hence it has to contain all explanations of scope. As hardly anybody thinks that our scope is narrower than it actually is, but most visitors think our scope extends further than it does, this help-centre site is mostly about the latter (as it is on many other SE sites).

Answer (score 4):

Bei Aufträgen gibt es normalerweise einen Auftraggeber und einen Auftragnehmer bzw. Beauftragten - während das Wort "Aufgabe" nur die zu erledigende Sache an sich benennt. Insofern kommt einem Auftrag im Normalfall auch eine höhere Bedeutung, höhere Gewichtung zu als einer Aufgabe. Aufträge sind oft an Verträge gebunden und Aufträge erhält man von anderen, während man sich Aufgaben auch selber stellen kann oder einem Aufgaben durch die Umstände gestellt werden können ("das Leben stellt mich vor eine harte Aufgabe").

Im Geschäftsumfeld vergibt man Aufträge an Firmen und Dienstleister. Da verwendet man nie das Wort "Aufgabe".

"Auftrag" impliziert im Normalfall eine konkrete, spezifische Anordnung durch jemand anderen. Man könnte sagen "Meine Mutter hat mir den Auftrag gegeben, Milch und Butter einzukaufen." (Sie hat es mir *aufgetragen*). Man könnte hier aber auch von einer Aufgabe sprechen, weil es keine förmliche Sache ist.

"Es ist meine Aufgabe, dir das zu sagen" kann bedeuten, dass ich es aufgrund irgendeines Umstandes (zum Beispiel dass die andere Person mein Freund ist) als meine Pflicht sehe, es ihm zu sagen.
"Ich habe den Auftrag, dir das zu sagen" bedeutet, dass mir jemand konkret diese Anordnung gegeben hat.

Abgesehen davon kann "Aufgabe" auch im Sinne einer Kapitulation verwendet werden und hat dann eine komplett andere Bedeutung.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Auftrag ist etwas, das größer ist als eine Aufgabe.

Einen "Auftrag" hat jemand, der etwas, z.B ein Projekt, für jemand anderen durchführen soll. Man könnte sich einen Agenten für eine Firma denken, der einen "Auftrag" hat. Man sagt/schreibt "Im Auftrag von..." nicht "Im Aufgabe von..."

Eine "Aufgabe" ist ein kleineres abgegrenzendes Problem zu lösen, z. B eine Hausaufgabe für Schüler. Hier fehlt auch ein deutlicher Auftraggeber, der vom Tat begünstigt wird.

Comment: Eltern haben die Aufgabe, ihre Kinder zu erziehen. Würdest du das als kleineres, stärker abgegrenztes Problem bezeichnen als dem örtlichen Elektronikhandel den Auftrag zu geben, Dir einen USB-Stick zuzusenden?

Comment: Aber Sie haben einen Erziehungsauftrag :-)

Comment: Guter Punkt. Mit dem Wort "Erziehungsauftrag" möchte man aber betonen, dass es einen Auftraggeber (bzw. Anspruchsträger) gibt - nämlich die Gesellschaft. Sowieso ist der Erziehungsauftrag für Eltern eine Lebensaufgabe. ;-)

Comment: @Tobi   Eine Aufgabe kann auch ein Teil von einem Auftrag ausmachen. Wenn jemand z.B. in Auftrag bekommt, einen Automotor zu reparieren, wäre vielleicht die erste Aufgabe, das Öl abzulassen. Ein Auftrag könnte wohl nicht ein Teilmoment einer Aufgabe sein? Daher denke ich, dass Auftrag ein größeres Begriff als Aufgabe sei.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, dass die beiden Wörter ziemlich genau dasselbe sind (Synonyme). Wahrscheinlich werden sie aber im Kontext unterschiedlich genutzt. Ein "Auftrag" wird meistens für grössere Sachen benutzt, zum Beispiel einen Bauauftrag, wenn ein Gebäude errichtet werden soll, da benutzt man nicht das Wort "Aufgabe". Eine Aufgabe ist geeignet für etwas kleineres, etwas, das nicht sehr lange dauert. Aber wie gesagt, gibt es keine klare Grenze oder Regel wo und wie man welches Wort verwendet.

Ich hoffe, dass dies geholfen hat.

Comment: Nein, sie können nicht synonym genutzt werden. In meiner Firma erstellen wir für Kunden Angebote und erhalten irgendwann einen **Auftrag**. Natürlich haben wir dann die **Aufgabe**, diesen Auftrag auszuführen, aber wir erhalten vom Kunden keine **Aufgabe**. Wären sie synonym, könnte man auch von Bauaufgabe sprechen oder von davon, dass Schüler Hausaufträge zu erledigen haben.

Comment: Siehe: "Kontext"

Comment: Wenn sie aber im Kontext unterschiedliche genutzt werden, sind es auch keine Synonyme.

Answer (score 0):

### Aufgabe

Eine Aufgabe ist eine Tätigkeit, die erledigt werden soll, und die mit Mühen verbunden ist. Eine Aufgabe entsteht aus einer Pflicht heraus. Diese Pflicht muss aber nicht unbedingt von jemand anderen ausgehen. Auch die Person, die die Aufgabe ausführt, kann der Urheber dieser Pflicht sein:

> Ich sehe es als meine Aufgabe an, streunende Katzen zu pflegen.

Etwas, das freiwillig, und ohne das innere Gefühl eine Pflicht zu erfüllen, getan wird, ist keine Aufgabe. Den ganzen Sonntag faul im Bett oder vor dem Fernseher zu verbringen ist keine Aufgabe, denn dieser Tätigkeit fehlt das Element der Pflichterfüllung.

Ohne äußeren Zwang die Bücher im Bücherregal alphabetisch zu ordnen, ist dann eine Aufgabe, wenn die Person, die das macht, dabei das Gefühl hat, dass das endlich mal gemacht werden sollte. Auf jeden Fall ist das Büchersortieren eine Aufgabe, wenn eine Person von einer anderen Person verlang, das zu tun.

Eine Aufgabe umfasst eine Beschreibung der Tätigkeit die zu erledigen ist, wobei diese Beschreibung ursprünglich auch implizit sein darf, aber zumindest explizit geäußert werden kann. Weiters ist eine Aufgabe an eine Person geknüpft, die diese Tätigkeit durchführen soll. Dabei können auch mehrere Personen mit derselben Tätigkeit beschäftigt sein, wie das z.B. bei Hausaufgaben in der Schule der Fall ist.

Zu einer Aufgabe gehört auch ein Kriterium anhand dessen festgestellt werden kann, ob die Aufgabe erfüllt ist. Häufig, aber nicht immer, gibt es auch einen Fertigstellungstermin.

Darüber hinaus gibt es auch Aufgaben, die man als *Zuständigkeiten* bezeichnen kann. Damit sind Tätigkeiten gemeint, die laufend gemacht werden müssen:

> Frau Steiner, ihre Aufgabe ist es, die Zimmer im ersten Stock sauber u halten.
>   Das Team 11 hat die Aufgabe, den Suchtgifthandel in der Innenstadt einzudämmen.

Auch in diesem Fall gibt es ein Fertigstellungskriterium (»Die Zimmer sind sauber«, »Es werden keine Suchtgifte gehandelt«). Dieses Kriterium beschreibt aber einen instabilen Zustand, und die Aufgabe besteht eben darin, diesen Zustand möglichst gut aufrecht zu erhalten.

---

### Auftrag

Ein Auftrag ist eine Aufgabe mit besonderen Eigenschaften. Die Tätigkeiten eines Auftrags werden immer explizit formuliert und haben ihrem Wesen nach den Charakter eines Befehls. Oftmals werden Aufträge auch schriftlich festgehalten. Zu einem Auftrag gehören zwei Personen oder Personengruppen, die nicht identisch sein können:

- **Auftraggeber**
  Das ist jene Person oder Gruppe, die die Tätigkeiten, die zu einem Auftrag gehören, festlegt. Der Auftraggeber wünscht oder fordert, dass diese Tätigkeiten erledigt werden.
- **Auftragnehmer**
  Das ist jene Person oder Gruppe, die vom Auftraggeber beauftragt wird. Der Auftragnehmer hat meist nur ein beschränktes Mitspracherecht bei der Festlegung des groben Inhalts des Auftrages. Details werden oftmals mit dem Auftraggeber ausverhandelt, bzw. bleiben dem Auftragnehmer allein überlassen.

Zwischen dem Auftraggeber und dem Auftragnehmer besteht eine hierarchische Beziehung. Der Auftragnehmer ist dem Auftraggeber untergeordnet.

Aufträge sind üblicherweise mit einer Gegenleistung verbunden. Das heißt: Der Auftragnehmer ist verpflichtet, den Auftrag im Sinne des Auftraggebers zu erfüllen, und der Auftraggeber ist im Gegenzug verpflichtet, den Auftragnehmer für seine Leistung zu entschädigen, meist in Form einer Geldzahlung.

---

Die Unterscheidung, ob eine Aufgabe auch ein Auftrag ist, kann nicht immer klar getroffen werden. Aber diese Kriterien können bei der Unterscheidung helfen:

**sicher kein Auftrag**

- Eine Tätigkeit ist kein Auftrag wenn sie keine Aufgabe ist, weil weder eine innere noch eine äußere Pflicht erfüllt wird. (»Ich werde heute mal den Nachmittag mit ein paar Kumpels in der Kneipe verbringen«)
- Eine Aufgabe ist dann kein Auftrag, wenn die Aufgabe aus inneren Antrieb erledigt wird, wenn es also keinen äußeren Auftraggeber gibt (»Seit Jahren will ich schon die Scheune neu streichen, heute mach ich es.«)

**sicher ein Auftrag**

- Wenn in einem Vertrag zwischen Auftraggeber und Auftragnehmer geregelt ist, was bis wann zu tun ist. (»Liefern Sie bis zum 8. Februar 500 Heckscheiben der Type ABC123«)
- Wenn ausdrücklich eine Gegenleistung vereinbart wird. (»Wenn du die Wäsche aufhängst und den Müll runterträgst, bekommst du am Abend ein Eis.)

Comment: Der Auftragnehmer ist dem Auftraggeber nicht untergeordnet. ich glaube, hier geraten Begriffe wie Auftrag und Befehl durcheinander.

Answer (score 0):

Eine Aufgabe ist etwas längerfristiges. Beispielsweise hat der Frisör in seinem Laden die Aufgabe, den Kunden die Haare zu schneiden.

Ein Auftrag ist etwas einmaliges und kurzfristiges. Beispielsweise, wenn der Frisör explizit die Haare der Frau Meier schneidet.

Answer (score -2):

In meinem Verständnis umreissen beide Wörter wie oben beschrieben ein Problem inhaltlich. Auftrag zieht zusätzlich noch eine zeitliche Begrenzung (und/oder Ressourcenbegrenzung wie Geld, Mitarbeiter, Arbeitsmittel,...), während Aufgabe diesbezüglich "offener" ist.

Comment: Aufträge können zeitlich unbegrenzt sein (Daueraufträge).

Comment: ...und die Lehrer haben es immer gehasst, wenn ich den zeitlichen Rahmen einer Hausaufgabe etwas offener gestaltet habe. :-)

Comment: Naja aber innerhalb des Zeitraums (1 Tag, 1 Woche,...)  hast Du selber gewählt wann Du diese erledigst. dito in einer Klausur: Du bekommst 5 Aufgaben gestellt,wann du (innerhalb deines Zeitbudgets) diese abarbeitest, liegt/lag in Deiner Verantwortung

Comment: ...und bei Aufträgen mit zeitlichen Fristen ist das anders?

Comment: Touche. Werde ab jetzt alle Energie darauf verwenden, in Elternabenden dafür zu kämpfen, ab sofort nur Hausaufträge zu verteilen. ;)

Comment: Ich denke es heisst "Hausaufgaben" und nicht "Hausaufträge", weil es die Aufgaben an sich benennt und nicht den Auftrag, diese zu erledigen - genauso wie eine Klausur eben aus Aufgaben und nicht aus Aufträgen besteht. Aber man hat vom Lehrer den Auftrag erhalten, diese Aufgaben im Rahmen der Klausur zu lösen. Hausaufgaben sind eine Reihe von Aufgaben, die man lösen muss. Der Lehrer hat einem den Auftrag dazu gegeben.

Comment: Dann sind wir aber wieder bei meiner ursprünglichen versuchten Abgrenzung Aufgabe/Auftrag hinsichtlich einer zeitlichen Beschränkung.  Der Lehrer gibt den Auftrag,bis morgen die Hausaufgaben abzuarbeiten.oder innerhalb 1h die Klausuraufgaben zu lösen.

Comment: Im Zusammenhang mit Hausaufgaben finde ich durchaus, dass man vom Auftrag sprechen könnte, die Hausaufgaben zu lösen. Aber dennoch können Aufgaben in einem Rätselmagazin oder in einem Computerspiel zeitliche Vorgaben haben und es wäre ziemlich konstruiert, da von einem Auftrag zu sprechen, den man vom Rätselheft oder vom Spiel erhalten hat. Aber da es bei einem Auftrag immer Auftragnehmer und einen Auftragnehmer, sowie im Normalfall bestimmte Rahmenbedingungen gibt, können Aufgaben natürlich sehr viel mehr sein. Ich denke nur nicht, dass man es an Dingen wie Zeit oder Geld festmachen kann.